# How to cast IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> with dynamic data

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

How to casting `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>` in dynamic data whether it is `int`, `object` or `string`

This is how I get my actual data:

```
List<Orders> order = new List<Orders>();
Customer[] cs = { new Customer { CustNum = 5, OtherAddress = "Hello" }, new 
Customer { CustNum = 986, OtherAddress = "Other" } };
Customer[] cso = { new Customer { OtherAddress = "T", CustNum = 5 }, new 
Customer { CustNum = 777, OtherAddress = "other" } };
order.Add(new Orders(code + 1, "ALFKI", i + 0, 2.3 * i, "Mumbari", "Berlin", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 2, "ANATR", i + 2, 3.3 * i, "Sydney", "Madrid", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 3, "ANTON", i + 1, 4.3 * i, "NY", "Cholchester", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 4, "BLONP", i + 3, 5.3 * i, "LA", "Marseille", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 5, "BOLID", i + 4, 6.3 * i, "Cochin", "Tsawassen", cs));
```

I'd like to convert this `IEnumerable` data into an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I just call the function with `PerformComplexDataOperation(order , "customer")`

```
private IQueryable PerformComplexDataOperation(this IEnumerable dataSource, string select)
{
    Type T = dataSource.GetElementType();
    IQueryable<T> data = dataSource.AsQueryable().Cast<typeof(dataSource)>();
    return data;
}
```

need to perform some other operation in it. I just paste overview of my code

Comment: some code example please?

Comment: "ienumerable generic type" - that's now how generics, nor ASP.NET Dynamic Data, work. Please tell us what you're *really* trying to do and why.

Comment: the only IEnumerable involved here is `order` and it's already generic `List<Orders>` so it's very unclear about your problem.

Comment: your method returns `IQueryable` (not `IQueryable<T>`) so looks like just  this `dataSource.AsQueryable()` is enough.

Comment: @KingKing  need to perform some other operation in it. I just paste overview of my code.

Comment: @karthik - Your `PerformComplexDataOperation` method does not make sense. It does not compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes i know i am trying to cast in that

Comment: @ZevSpitz how can i achieve in dynamic

Comment: `AsQueryable` makes sense only if your input `dataSource` is actually some IQueryable instance. Otherwise you should use `OfType` to filter for all the types you want to specifically process through (as you know beforehand with 3 types: int, string and object).

Comment: Consider using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core). This will allow the following query: `var query = data.AsQueryable().Select("customer");` (assuming your `Orders` type has a `Customer` property).

Comment: @karthik - What's the point? You're returning it as `IQueryable` anyway - which is just `IEnumerable` really since the source was. This method seems pointless. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @ZevSpitz how can i select this field in dynamic customer[0].Otheraddress

Comment: @Enigmativity I just trying to use lamba expression. That's why i am converting non-generic to generic type.

Comment: @karthik - you need to rewrite your question. as it stands it is pretty much incomprehensible. no one has a clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: @karthik - What do you mean by "trying to use lamba expression"?

Comment: @karthik - I'm confused - your actual data is a strongly typed list. What has that got to do with converting `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @karthik See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47173788/111794).

Comment: @ZevSpitz Ok I will check

Comment: @Enigmativity i know , it is a strongly typed list. I have two different project i need to send  a data to another one project function.

Comment: @karthik Where is this function going to be located? Can you define an interface or a shared `abstract` base class for both types?

Comment: @karthik - Then you can send in strongly-typed data. There's no need for all this `IEnumerable` conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually want to use generics only when you can know the type at compile time. For example, the LINQ `Select` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` takes two generic parameters -- the source type, and the result type.

When you write your code, the compiler "knows" the source type and result type based on how you've written your code:

```
var lst = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
var query = lst.Select(x => x.ToString();

//the compiler fills in the generic type parameters as follows:
var query = lst.Select<int,string>(x => x.ToString());
```

If at compile-time you know the type, then you can simply `Cast` the `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable` to the appropriate compile-time type:

```
IEnumerable lst = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
var query = lst.Cast<int>().Select(x => x*x);
```

Or better yet, there is no need to limit the variable to the non-generic `IEnumerable`; you can use `var` as above, or explicitly type the variable:

```
IEnumerable<int> lst = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
```

---

However, I suspect that you don't know the type at compile-time, in which case generics won't help you.<sup>1</sup>

In that case, you can use the [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) library, which enables you to use LINQ methods by passing in strings instead of delegates/expressions. For example:

```
// assuming your Orders type has a Customer property
var query = data.AsQueryable().Select("Customer");
```

String expressions can be more complex, e.g. using the `.` operator to navigate properties, and `[...]` for array indexes:

```
// For each Order, will return the OtherAddress of the first Customer
var query = data.AsQueryable().Select("Customers[0].OtherAddress");
```

---

<sup>1. Actually, you *could* use a combination of reflection and the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to construct your own expressions, if you really want to.</sup>

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm assuming that the OP has multiple data sets of varying types, whose only base type is `IEnumerable`. Yet there is still some complex operation to be performed on any of those types, which the OP wants to control via strings. It is possible to construct `Expressions` to do the same, but using [`System.Dynamic.Linq.Core`](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) or some other similar variant, is much simpler.

Comment: That explains the final suggestion in your answer, but everything before the "However, I suspect..." doesn't seem relevant - it's explaining something that the OP isn't trying to do.

Comment: @Enigmativity _explaining something that the OP isn't trying to do_ Not quite sure; the OP still hasn't responded to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173169/how-to-casting-ienumerable-to-ienumerablet-in-dynamic-data-whether-it-is-int-o/47173788?noredirect=1#comment81297136_47173169).

Comment: Yes, it is a very confusing question.